# What makes a Bytestring "lazy"?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, bytestring

I am learning Haskell but having some difficulty understanding how exactly lazy ByteStrings work. [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) says that "Lazy ByteStrings use a lazy list of strict chunks which makes it suitable for I/O streaming tasks". In contrast, a strict list is stored as one large array.

What are these "chunks" in lazy byteStrings? How does your compiler know just how large a chunk should be? Further, I understand that the idea behind a lazy list is that you don't have to store the entire thing, which thus allows for infinite lists and all of that. But how is this storage implemented? Does each chunk have a pointer to a next chunk?

Many thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the [definition of the lazy `ByteString` here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.html#ByteString):

```hs
data ByteString = Empty | Chunk {-# UNPACK #-} !S.ByteString ByteString
    deriving (Typeable)
```

so `Chunk` is one data-constructor - the first part is a strict (`!`) *strict* (`S.`) `ByteString` and then some more `Chunks` or `Empty` via the second recursive (lazy) `ByteString` part.

Note that the second part does not have the `(!)` there - so this can be a [*GHC thunk*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Thunk) (the **lazy** stuff in Haskell) that will only be forced when you *need* it (for example *pattern-match* on it).

That means a lazy `ByteString` is either `Empty` or you get a strict (you can think of this as already *loaded* if you want) part or *chunk* of the complete string with a *lazy* remaining/rest/tail `ByteString`.

As about the size that depends on the code that is generating this lazy bytestring - the compiler does not come into this.

You can see this for [`hGetContents`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Lazy.html#hGetContents):

```hs
hGetContents = hGetContentsN defaultChunkSize
```

where [`defaultChunkSize`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.html#defaultChunkSize) is defined to be `32 * 1024 - 2 * sizeOf (undefined :: Int)` - so a bit less than **32kB**

And yes the *rest* (snd. argument to `Chunk`) can be seen as a pointer to the next `Chunk` or `Empty` (just like with a *normal* list).

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I'd add to this answer that the primary reason to use a lazy ByteString is to do lazy IO. Lazy IO is kinda complicated and hard to reason about. _Caveat lector_!